# Can I obtain an unwrapped singleton type in Scala with a simple method?

Tags: scala, type-inference, shapeless, singleton-type

In Scala, in a discussion around Miles Sabin's shapeless library, I've seen code like this:

```
def sing[T <: String](t: T): Option[t.type] = Some(t)
```

where something like this:

```
val name = sing("name")
```

has type `Option[Constant(name).type]`. I thought “why wrap it in an `Option`”? But if I try this:

```
def sing2[T <: String](t: T): t.type = t
val name2 = sing2("name")
```

then `name2` has type `String`, whereas I would have expected it to be `Constant(name).type`. What am I missing? Is there a workaround that does not involve wrapping the singleton type?

Comment: With *scala-2.11.2*, I get `name: Option[String("name")] = Some(name)` for the first example. Which scalac do you use?

Comment: It's the Scala IDE with version 2.11.4. What do you get for the second example with `name2`?

Comment: I get the `name2: String` as well. Actually I have no idea how to construct a value of type `String(<string-literal>)`, for now it seems you must have a name for the literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known quirk of scalac.

Singleton types are a compiler internal and they've been there for a long time, but they've never been meant to be exposed to the users. So, there's no guarantee about their "API" and as a matter of fact scalac tries to make them "disappear" whenever it can.

This is pretty much the reason why Miles had to use a [Witness](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L28) type to wrap singleton types whenever needed (e.g. extensible record keys).

Apparently, wrapping them in a container causes the compiler to retain the actual type, and this is what happens with `Option`.

As Oleg mentioned in the other answer, there's an ongoing effort to make singleton type officially part of the language: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that *scalac* upcasts the type. I have no idea, if it's by design or a bug. If you force the type:

```
def sing2[T <: String](t: T): t.type = t
val n = "name"
val name2: n.type = sing2(n)
// name2: n.type = name
```

---

It seems you can't construct a value of type `String(<string-literal>)`, only with bounded name:

```
scala> sing2("name")
res0: String = name

scala> val n = "name"
n: String = name

scala> sing2(n)
res1: n.type = name
```

---

But you can't say

```
val name2: n.type = sing("name")
```

because

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("name")
 required: n.type
```

And neither

```
name2: "name".type = sing2("name")
// or
name2: "name" = sing2("name")
```

But there is work on the latter: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/42.type.html